# $10$ players are to play in a tennis tournament. The number of pairings for the first round is?

Tags: combinatorics

The options are
A)$10!/(2^5)5!$

B)$2^{10}$

C)$45$

D)$90$

The number of ways how $2$ players are selected are in $45$ ways. But I think I am missing something here....
Help!

Comment: Why do you think you're missing something here? Isn't that the answer?

Comment: I think the first round is a set of five games, each involving two people, to make the total of ten players.  It is not about tennis, but about what a round of a tournament is.  How many ways are there to divide ten people into five pairs?  Choice A is missing parentheses.  What you have written is $\frac{10!}{2^5}5!$ but you mean $\frac{10!}{2^5\cdot 5!}$

Comment: I think its $\Pi_{i=0}^4(10-2i)C2$ but like, that's not a choice so I guess Occulms razor says its $10C2=45$ but for sure complain to the source about the wording.

Comment: Oops! Divide my answer by $5!$ if the order of matches doesn't matter.

Comment: The answer is A and it's 10!/(2^5)5!, not 10! ×5!/2^5

Comment: @Demonic99 Indeed I just realized after the edit; line all 10 players up, and count them off 2 at a time, that will be your first round matches. There are 10! ways to line them up and downstairs just accounts for degeneracy [IE it dosn't matter the order of pairings (5!) nor the order of the players in each pairing $(2!)^5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 10! ways to line up 10 players. Put a bar inbetween each pair of players. For example;

$0 1 | 2 3 | 4 5 | 6 7 | 8 9$<- is one way to do round one for players labeled 0-9.

Now it dosn't matter the order that the blocks are in; $0 1 | 6 7 | 4 5 | 2 3 | 8 9$ would encode the same 1st round as the one above, so we divide by $5!$ to account for all ways to permute the pairs of players. Nor does it matter the order of the players **within each pair** . $10 | 76 | 54 | 32 | 98$ still encodes the same 1st round. We must account for all 5 transpositions of which there are $2!^5$ So we indeed have a)
$$\frac{10!}{5!2^5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Because we are constrained by the multiple choice options, we would   construe it as $\frac{10!}{2^55!}$ but actually the simplest way to get the numerical answer is by noting that the first person has $9$ choices, the second $7$ choices, and so on thus $9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1$ or more succinctly using the double factorial,$\;9!!$

Also, to get the logic for answer **A**, we can simply conceive it as $5$ *unlabeled* teams of $2$,

thus $\dbinom{10}{2,2,2,2,2}\Bigg/5!$